# Can't access SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in a company and using previous employee's laptop, and when I try to open SQL Server Management Studio, it already has server that running but I can log in using Windows authentication.

I think it's because every employee has an ID that will be used as user for log in on the laptop, and now I can't log in into SQL Server Management Studio because I have a different user for Windows authentication.

If it's true then how can I log in into SQL Server Management Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how your SQL Server is setup you can log in using the following methods and setup your windows account:

1. Log in using SQL Server authentication such as the 'SA' account and setup your windows authentication.
2. If known, logon to the machine with the previous employee's account, login to the SSMS and setup your windows authentication, logout of windows and log back in with your account.
3. Request someone who has access (with relevant permissions) to set you up with access using windows authentication.